# Laravel Livewire - unable to read property "name" on string

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-9

I have a multiselect drop down in a livewire component that initially displays a list of available locations that a user can be attached to when creating the user. The initial load of the modal showing this dropdown is fine, and displays the locations, allows you to select, everything works.

However, when I submit the form, I'm getting an `Attempt to read property "name" on string` exception, but it's not even getting to the validation method. I'm having a hard time understanding what's happening behind the scenes with Livewire. Is it immediately trying to re-render the modal with the submitted data?

Here's the modal:

```
<x-modal class="modal-md" modalTitle="Create Users" id="createUserModal" submitMethod="create">
        @slot('body')
            <div class="row">
                <div class="mb-3 col-md-12">
                    <x-input.group label="First Name" for="first_name" :error="$errors->first('user.first_name')">
                        <x-input.text wire:model.defer="user.first_name" id="first_name" name="first_name" value="{{ $user->first_name ?? '' }}" />
                    </x-input.group>
                </div>

                <div class="mb-3 col-md-12">
                    <x-input.group label="Last Name" for="last_name" :error="$errors->first('user.last_name')">
                        <x-input.text wire:model.defer="user.last_name" id="last_name" name="last_name" value="{{ $user->last_name ?? '' }}" />
                    </x-input.group>
                </div>

                <div class="mb-3 col-md-12">
                    <x-input.group label="Phone" for="phone" :error="$errors->first('user.phone')">
                        <x-input.text wire:model.defer="user.phone" id="phone" name="phone" value="{{ $user->phone ?? '' }}" />
                    </x-input.group>
                </div>

                <div class="mb-3 col-md-12">
                    <x-input.group label="Email" for="email" :error="$errors->first('user.email')">
                        <x-input.text wire:model.defer="user.email" id="email" name="email" value="{{ $user->email ?? '' }}" />
                    </x-input.group>
                </div>

                <div class="mb-3 col-md-12">
                    <x-input.group label="Locations" for="locations" :error="$errors->first('locations')">
                        <x-input.multiselect wire:model.defer="locations" id="locations">
                            @foreach ($locations as $location)
<-- ERROR OCCURS HERE:-->
                                <option name="{{ $location->name }}" id="{{ $location->id }}" value="{{ $location->id }}" wire:key="{{ $location->id }}">
                                    {{ $location->id }} - {{ $location->name }}
                                </option>
                            @endforeach
                        </x-input.multiselect>
                    </x-input.group>
                </div>

                <div class="mb-3 col-md-12">
                    <x-input.group label="Role" for="role_id" :error="$errors->first('user.role_id')" helpText="Selecting Non-User will create a contact only, and no invite will be sent.">
                        <x-input.select wire:model.defer="user.role_id" id="role_id" placeholder="Select a role">
                            @foreach ($roles as $role)
                                <option name="{{ $role->name }}" id="{{ $role->id }}" value="{{ $role->id }}" wire:key="{{ $role->id }}">
                                    {{ $role->name }}
                                </option>
                            @endforeach
                        </x-input.select>
                    </x-input.group>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endslot
    </x-modal>
```

and here's the modal livewire component:

```
class Create extends Component
{
    public User $user;
    public $roles;
    public $locations;

    protected $rules = [
        'user.first_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:150'],
        'user.last_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:150'],
        'user.email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:App\Models\User,email'],
        'user.phone' => 'required|string|min:12|max:12|regex:/^\d{3}\-\d{3}\-\d{4}$/|unique:App\Models\User,phone',
        'user.role_id' => 'required|exists:roles,id',
        'locations.*.id' => 'required|exists:locations,id'
    ];

    protected $messages = [
        'user.role_id.required' => 'The role field is required.'
    ];


    public function mount(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->role_id = '';
        $this->roles = Auth::user()->assignable_roles;
        $this->locations = Auth::user()->locations;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.users.create');
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $validatedData = $this->validate();

        try {
            DB::beginTransaction();

            $newUserData = array_merge($validatedData, ['password' => Hash::make('YGWwxjsxrmsgRJpDrVRd')]);
            $user = User::create($newUserData);

            $locations = Arr::flatten($newUserData['locations']);
            $user->locations()->sync($locations);

            DB::commit();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            DB::rollback();
            throw $e;
        }

        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('hideModal');
        $this->emit('refreshUsers');
        $this->resetExcept('roles', 'locations');
    }
}
```

and here's the main blade file where the modal is called from:

```
<div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-2">
        <h4 class="page-title text-dark">Users</h4>
        @if (Auth::user()->isInternal())
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-icon-text" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#createUserModal">
                <i class="mdi mdi-account-plus btn-icon-prepend me-2"></i>Add User
            </button>
        @endif
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 grid-margin stretch-card">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <x-table search="true">
                        @slot('head')
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Role</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                        @endslot
                        @slot('body')
                            @forelse($users as $user)
                                <x-table.row id="{{ $user->id }}" includeStatus="true" :status="$user->deleted_at">
                                    <td>{{ $user->id }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $user->first_name }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $user->last_name }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $user->role->name }}</td>
                                </x-table.row>
                            @empty
                                <x-table.empty-row colSpan="6" />
                            @endforelse
                        @endslot

                        @slot('paginationLinks')
                            {{ $users->links() }}
                        @endslot
                    </x-table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<livewire:users.create />
```

And here's the livewire controller for that page:

```
class UserIndex extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    public $search;
    public $roles;
    public $user;

    protected $paginationTheme = 'bootstrap';

    protected $listeners = ['refreshUsers' => '$refresh'];

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->search = '';
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.users.index', [
            'users' => User::withTrashed()->search(['first_name', 'last_name'], $this->search)->paginate(5)
        ]);
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        return redirect()->route('users.edit', ['user' => $id]);
    }
}
```

This is what's going over in the payload:

[image]

Comment: Where is this error? On which line? You call "name" property on difference objects.

Comment: Sorry, I added a comment to the code. The error is happening in the foreach loop where it's populating the locations drop down. in the option tag it apparently is trying to reference `$location->name` and can't?  I don't know if I need to re-populate locations as a collection? Maybe it's seeing locations as an array of IDs like what I'm submitting? I just don't understand what's happening between the submit and this error.

Comment: Which multiselect are you using?

Comment: @itepifanio I'm using select2 plugin.

Comment: use {{ dd($location) }} or {{ dd($location->name) }} line before error in blade to debug

Comment: I asked about the multiselect because if was a custom one the javascript could be the bug error. 
Something a little weird about your code is that you're rendering the 'locations' and you wire:models are referring to 'locations' as well. Have you tried to change the wire:models to something like locationsSelected?